# Volume of a region enclosed between a surface and various planes

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

Can somebody explain how to find the volume of a region enclosed between a surface and various planes.
For example -
If $S$ is a region enclosed by the surface $z= y^2$ and the planes $z=1$ , $x=0$ , $x=1$, $y=-1$ and $y=1$ what is the volume of $S$?

Comment: If my answer helped you, you may click the accept button next to my answer.

Comment: It helped but there is no such option available here to accept. Thank you though!

Comment: If you're on a computer then it should be under the downvote button on the left (it will turn green after you accepted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you draw it (first the function $z=y^2$ and then extend the $x$-dimension), then you will see that you need to calculate the volume of a $1\times 2\times 1$-cuboid minus the volume under $z=f(x,y)=y^2$ on $[0,1]\times [-1,1]$, so just calculate $\int_0^1\int_{-1}^1 f(x,y)dydx$ and substract this from the volume of the cuboid to find the volume of $S$.